# how to get the view that is represented in the Knowledge Demo

Tags: knowledge

In the Video demo you can see a full site view, is that something out of the box or do we have to create it by hand. Also if there is a tutorial of how to recreate that would be great:

Video Link: https://youtu.be/d3jD25SNp6g?t=70

You can see the site preview here:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot you have is a Salesforce community cloud .Communities in Salesforce provides you templates to quickly create pages with knowledge enabled .You may want to check communities getting started guide for more info

Comment: Thanks for the info, some one else provided the following links which walked me through the steps to do this but for some reason they deleted their response.

Comment: Here they are: 

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/workbook_service_cloud.pdf

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/service_cloud

Comment: I wish SalesForce would mention this right away, I spent a whole day trying to recreate their custom site.

Comment: If you Google Communities implementation guide in Salesforce you will get a PDF .Even help.salesforce.com will have relevant info

Comment: Thanks @Mohith, this is the guideline that I was using from SF. Granted they do mention communities but not as explicit as this forum :) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_knowledge_implementation_guide.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Lightning communities are Out of the box templates that allow you to leverage the use of components to build them through a drag and drop editor (community builder).

There are several guides that can help you to get started:

[Enabling Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable.htm&type=0)

[What template should I use?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=siteforce_commtemp_intro.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=206.20)

[Partner Built Community components](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2016/05/salesforce-community-cloud-lightning-components.html)